# Do you know any instant / standalone bug tracker?

Tags: bug-tracking

**Background**

Recently I finished my project and the client is testing it in their office. Unfortunately people who are testing it are in a network without internet access (for security reasons).

**Question**

I'm looking for small / standalone bug tracker that I could just run on one of my client test servers (without installation) for adhoc bug tracking (on something like Cassini or similar). Do you have any experiences with that?

Comment: How do you run something without installing it?

Comment: @Jim - fair enough, although echo 'Bug tracking system' is probably not the answer here...

Comment: @Paddy True. Worth a shot though!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). It's a self-contained distributed version control system with built-in wiki and bug tracker. It works perfectly well as stand-alone issue tracker, regardless of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need no installation footprint, then you might be best placed with an excel file on a shared drive (although this does sound like a bit of a nightmare).

Bugzilla is pretty decent and easy enough to install...

Comment: Excel files is what I use right now (.. and Yes it's a nightmare ;) Bugzilla is nice but it's to complicated for my purpose (perl + mysql + some webserver ... it's just an overkill). For me something that stores bugs in xml file would be just fine. Holidays are coming so maybe I will enter 'portable web server" in google, press "I'm feeling lucky" and start coding :P

Answer (score 1):

At the end I used [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/) which is a complete WAMPP stack + [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) as a bug tracker. After configuring it on my machine I just copied it on one of the test servers and run it through the remote desktop. Works like a charm.